# customDistribution compare Agents in Queue

Tags: anylogic

I'm using CustomDistribution of Type: Discrete with observed sample to get differerent Delay times in my Service Block. Now i want to use Agent comparison to let the agent with the lower customDstribution Value to get manufactered first. i want to get a shortest Processing Time Priority in the queue.

I've tried to use `agent1.cD_M1>=agent2.cD_M1` (cD_M1 is my customDistribution), but i get the error (The operator >= is undefined fpt the argument type(s).

Is there a way to compare these values and when yes how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually draw a value from your distributions:

`agent1.cD_M1.get()>=agent2.cD_M1-get()`

Start using code-complete to see all possible options you have:
[image]